# CSS Transition (Translate) Flickering

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have tried both

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

And

```
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
```

To resolve the flickering that happens when the transition is fired, but nothing works. 
Are there any other ways of resolving this issue?

Comment: can you please provide a link? did you try adding a css3 transition time, to even 100ms if you want it almost instant?

Comment: Yes, a working link would help. Also, on what browser ? Usually these problems arise on IOS.

Answer (score 2):

This is rather unscientific, but try adding `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`

It should make no difference (translation of 0,0,0 means "do nothing" after all), it'll probably make no difference in the future, but it does sometimes force 3d-acceleration to be used in such a way that can smooth out animations and transitions. I've found it nicely sorts out some animation that flicker horribly in safari. (and flicker really, really horribly in safari on iPad).

It's a bit 1990s add-the-magic-words-to-the-webpage, but it does sometimes work.